# Prevent a window to open in viewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

In iOS, is there a possibility of stopping a view from loading in the `viewWillAppear` ?

Something like `[self close];` ?

What I am trying to do is:

- create a view with an object partially loaded
- display the view
- in the viewWillAppear, I finish the object loading and fill the view fields
- if the object loading fails, I do not want to show the view

I know that it is not really the good way to do that,
but it's existing code that I do not want to change too much.

Comment: what are u trying to achieve, could you be elaborate and explain your problem for helping you out ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question, but if you just try to have a view inside a viewController not to be shown at the beginning and to appear later you can easily viewName.hide = YES; it in viewWillAppear and then viewName.hide = NO; when you want it to be shown.